# How to save bytes to an image and access it from Bottle

Tags: python, bottle

I'm working on an API wrapper for Snapchat using Python and Bottle, but in order to return the file (retrieved by the Python script) I have to save the bytes (returned by Snapchat) to a .jpg file. I'm not quite sure how I will do this and still be able to access the file so that it can be returned. Here's what I have so far, but it returns a 404.

```
@route('/image')
def image():
    username = request.query.username
    token = request.query.auth_token
    img_id = request.query.id
    return get_blob(username, token, img_id)

def get_blob(usr, token, img_id):
    # Form URL and download encrypted "blob"
    blob_url = "https://feelinsonice.appspot.com/ph/blob?id={}".format(img_id)
    blob_url += "&username=" + usr + "&timestamp=" + str(timestamp()) + "&req_token=" + req_token(token)
    enc_blob = requests.get(blob_url).content  
    # Save decrypted image
    FileUpload.save('/images/' + img_id + '.jpg')
    img = open('images/' + img_id + '.jpg', 'wb')
    img.write(decrypt(enc_blob))
    img.close()
    return static_file(img_id + '.jpg', root='/images/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you intentionally using a relative path when you write the image file?  (File location would then depend on your program's current working dir.)

Perhaps changing this line

```
img = open('images/' + img_id + '.jpg', 'wb')
```

to this

```
img = open('/images/' + img_id + '.jpg', 'wb')
```

will do the trick?

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just saving it to a local folder (since I'm running it on localhost temporarily) and then realized that when I saved it I was using `img = open('images/' + img_id + '.jpg', 'wb')` and when I was returning it I was using `static_file(img_id + '.jpg', root='/images/'`